# How to create multiple UIButtons positioned horizontally with Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, storyboard

I am trying to create four buttons within `UIViewBar` positioned one by one with auto layout and also everybutiton having `Imageview` on right side arrow. Now I dont know how to achieve for all the `iOS` devices. It should change size and spaces based one device width. See below Image

[image]

Comment: What's actually your question? What have you done/tried yet? What should the constraints be?

Comment: add constraints to each control with view

Comment: How to do that? Could you please give me an example? @Balaji

Comment: its quite easy ,you want to display this 4 button depend upon the device i am right?

Comment: YES. looks like above but It should change spaces If I run iPad or iPhone 6,etc.@Kishore

Comment: ok wait i give you solution after i tried @android

Comment: for this, best solution is adding button to UIStackView

Comment: Did u tried @KishoreKumar

Comment: @android did u got your answer

Answer (score 0):

Select all your buttons and click on 'pin' in the storyboard (it in the right bottom corner) like in the below image

[image]

add 'Leading', 'Tralling', 'Height', 'Equal width' constraints

[image]

and select 'Align' while selecting the all four button(left to the 'pin')
and add 'Vertically in container' constraint.

[image]

or else you can add 'Top constraint' instead of 'Vertically in container' constraint.

Hey I don't know this will help you or not. But lets give it a try.:)

Comment: For iPad its showing good but iPhone Its looks like unalignment.@NuN